# data-field="time" not supporting in ng-model="" of angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have used popup for time picker in my angularjs project.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dtBox").DateTimePicker();
    });

</script>
```

My text box input tag 
 value inserting as null.

Comment: Where did you use angular?

Comment: <input data-field="time"  data-format="hh:mm AA" type="text" ng-model="dtlitem.answers" >

Comment: Have a look on angular's document of [input-time](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btime%5D)

Comment: type="time" not setting values in input box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular UI has got a date picker https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date so instead of using Jquery why not use this?

It's never a good thing to combine Jquery widgets in Angular. It's like having two steering wheels...

Comment: sir, i want the time picker

Comment: Can i suggest time picker for angularjs...for adding my input box.. 
<input  type="text" ng-model="dtlitem.answers" >